# Best way to check on heap in V8

Tags: node.js, v8

What is the best way, say for an Express server, to check that the overall heap is not growing over time in V8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`process.memoryUsage()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_memoryusage) returns an object containing the total (`heapTotal`) and used (`heapUsed`) amounts of memory used by the heap.